# What is the analogon of Mockito.spy/doReturn in EasyMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, easymock

Imagine, I have following class:

```
public class TestClass {
    public class Index<X> {

    }
    public class IndexData {
        private final Index<?> index;

        private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock =
            new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

        public IndexData(final Index<?> index) {
            super();
            this.index = index;
        }

        public Index<?> getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public Lock getReadLock() {
            return lock.readLock();
        }

        public Lock getWriteLock() {
            return lock.writeLock();
        }   
    }

    public void add(final InputClass input)
    {
        final IndexData index = getIndex(input);

        final Lock lock = index.getWriteLock();
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // Do something here, which requires synchronization
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    protected IndexData getIndex(final InputClass input) {
        // Some logic of getting the index for input
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test, which verifies that

1. in the `add` method, `index.getWriteLock()` is used (not `index.getReadLock()`),
2. the lock is taken and
3. released.

Using Mockito I can write a test like this:

```
@Test
public void testAddUsesWriteLock() {
    // Prepare
    final TestClass objectUnderTest = Mockito.spy(new TestClass());
    final InputClass input = Mockito.mock(InputClass.class);
    final IndexData indexData = Mockito.mock(IndexData.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(indexData).when(objectUnderTest).getIndex(input);
    final Lock lock = Mockito.mock(Lock.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(lock).when(indexData).getWriteLock();

    // Invoke method under test
    objectUnderTest.add(input);

    // Verify
    Mockito.verify(indexData).getWriteLock();
    Mockito.verify(indexData, Mockito.never()).getReadLock();
    Mockito.verify(lock).lock();
    Mockito.verify(lock).unlock();
}
```

How can I do the same thing with EasyMock?

Concrete: How can I the `getIndex` method return a mock in EasyMock (line `Mockito.doReturn(indexData).when(objectUnderTest).getIndex(input)`) ?

Note: You can find the code of this example [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/9f97e511-1581-49d8-b8f6-0e6982186b4a/a1c17b315809caed9bab5e25ef30f4a7) .

Comment: Apologies if you only want an exact answer relating to Easymock, but I think you need to take a step back and ask yourself why you're having to `spy()` the class you are trying to test. This is generally [considered a code smell](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212493/is-spying-on-tested-class-bad-practice). I thought it worth mentioning in case you are new to writing tests of this nature, and have the option to refactor the code.

Comment: @Brad I know that this practice may be considered a bad design. However, for me it is more important to test everything I want than to have an elegant design. Basically, I want to be able to write an automated test for most errors that I detect manually. In my particular situation this is simply more important than nice design. And the code cannot be refactored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the spirit of providing a possible solution (and contrary to my comments above) you could try one of the following

**Option 1**

If `TestClass` implements an interface you could achieve a similar test using [andDelegateTo()](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html#andDelegateTo-java.lang.Object-) as described in this post that talks about [Easymock not supporting spying](http://blog.octo.com/en/easymock-facts-fallacies/)

**Option 2**

Remove your need for spying by extending the `TestClass` specifically for your testing requirements. This is a common approach to dealing with legacy code bases where you cannot alter the code under test.

I will use Mockito in this example so that it is aligned with your question, however the concept will work the same with Easymock.

```
public class TestClassUsingMockito {
    /**
    We extend the original class under test so that we can override the creation of IndexData and
    thereby remove the responsibility of creating this object from the @Test method
    */
    private class ClassForTesting extends TestClass {

        private Lock lock;
        private IndexData indexData;

        public ClassForTesting(IndexData indexData, Lock lock) {
            this.indexData = indexData;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        protected IndexData getIndex(InputClass input) {
            return indexData;
        }
    }

    /**
    Look Ma' no more Spys!
    */
    @Test
    public void testAddUsesWriteLock() {        
        // Prepare
        final Lock lock = Mockito.mock(Lock.class);
        final IndexData indexData = Mockito.mock(IndexData.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(lock).when(indexData).getWriteLock();
        // ... now use your new subclass for testing
        final TestClass objectUnderTest = new ClassForTesting(indexData, lock);
        final InputClass input = Mockito.mock(InputClass.class);

        // Invoke method under test
        objectUnderTest.add(input);

        // Verify
        Mockito.verify(indexData).getWriteLock();
        Mockito.verify(indexData, Mockito.never()).getReadLock();
        Mockito.verify(lock).lock();
        Mockito.verify(lock).unlock(); 
    }
}
```

**What is the analogon of Mockito.spy/doReturn in EasyMock?**

So having removed the need for a Spy() in your tests the Mockito call

```
Mockito.doReturn(lock).when(indexData).getWriteLock();
```

Can be written in EasyMock as

```
expect(indexData.getWriteLock()).andStubReturn(lock);
```

**EasyMock example of the same Mockito test above**

```
public class TestClassUsingEasymock extends EasyMockSupport {

    private class ClassForTesting extends TestClass {

        private Lock lock;
        private IndexData indexData;

        public ClassForTesting(IndexData indexData, Lock lock) {
            this.indexData = indexData;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        protected IndexData getIndex(InputClass input) {
            return indexData;
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testAddUsesWriteLock() {
        // Prepare
        final Lock lock = createNiceMock(Lock.class);       
        final IndexData indexData = createNiceMock(IndexData.class);
        EasyMock.expect(indexData.getWriteLock()).andStubReturn(lock);

        // ... now use your new subclass for testing
        final TestClass objectUnderTest = new ClassForTesting(indexData, lock);
        final InputClass input = createNiceMock(InputClass.class);

        lock.lock();
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();

        lock.unlock();
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();

        replayAll();

        // Invoke method under test
        objectUnderTest.add(input);

        // Verify
        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will award this bounty to you, if you provide an EasyMock example of the code. I already saw elsewhere a solution similar to what you suggest, but it also was written in Mockito and I'm too stupid to map `Mockito.doReturn(lock).when(indexData).getWriteLock();` to EasyMock.

Comment: In EasyMock use `expect(indexData.getWriteLock()).andStubReturn(lock);`

Comment: EasyMock example added

Comment: Thanks. I need to wait 20 hours, before I can award the bounty (can't award it right now because of SO's regulations).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Tx.